# Where is the "sync selection" option?

Tags: texturing, interface, uv

When I try to select an island in a uv map it says "Cannot select linked when sync selection is enabled".

I know I have to disable it with this button:
[image]

But it is not here:
[image]

So where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second screenshot is of the header in the 3D view, but the setting you are looking for is in the header of the *UV/Image editor*:

[image]

Comment: @user2320445 Only if you really want to. If you don't delete it this can help others with the same question :)

Comment: doesnt choosing an island chooses the same portion of the model?

Comment: I chose an island but all the model is still selected , why ?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible atm. Thats how it would work if sync selection was enabled, but for some reason it must be disabled. Not sure why this is :/

Comment: so it is a paradox , sync enabled -> not able to choose , sync disabled->wont choose , so there is no point in sync? what should i do?

Comment: @user2320445 Unfortunately I think the best you can do right now is select the island manually (C, M, and Ctrl LMB can help a bit)

Comment: You can sync-select these islands with the L key in face select mode, but not in vertex select mode.

Answer (score 3):

[image: This option is available after turning off two blue arrows in Edit mode]

This option is available after turning off two blue arrows in Edit mode in Blender 2.8

Comment: Did they remove these icons/controls in 2.9? Recently updated and can't find them, wondering if I need to turn them on somehow or if they're just gone....

Answer (score 0):

In 3.3.1 I couldn't find the UV Sync Selection or the rest of the toolbar in the UV Editor but realised it was because I didn't have my model selected in Edit Mode. If yours is missing it's probably because you're still in Object Mode.