# Why doesn't selecting a UV island select the corresponding vertices in the model?

Tags: texturing, uv, selection-tools

I have a model and I selected an island from my UV map with <kbd>L</kbd>, but those vertices didn't get selected on the mesh. Why is that?

Is there any way to quickly select UV islands on the mesh?

[image]

---

This is a follow-up question to [Where is the "sync selection" option?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27298/599)

Comment: @RayMairlot I think the question is specifically about selecting *islands*, not just faces. The comments on this question might help provide some context: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27298/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now possible as of [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBaff4aa173a78c7bbd7d08666f995d48ea18cdb50). Will be in 2.75 or [any recent development build](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599).

To use it, enable *Sync Selection*, switch to face select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>), and enjoy ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, only the vertices you select on your mesh, in Edit mode, will be visible in the UV editor, and what you select in UV editor has no effect on the mesh selection;
however, if you enable the **Selection sync**, found in the **UV editor**'s header, you can select vertices in either editor and have the selection sync in the other one.

[image]

Comment: if you enable sync you cant select only one island the whole islnads will be selected

Comment: yes because there is no island selection on the 3D view and it need to be identical ; you can see that selection modes change when it's enabled

Comment: You can select islands with 'L' from the object if you're in face mode and marked seams. (Blender will use the seams as island bounds, not the unwrapped UV islands if they are different)

Comment: If you enable sync selection and then try to select an island, blender will give an error.