# How to show 'Individual UVs' in a multi UV map?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

***Separate UV maps*** have been created for the character's parts, e.g. shirt, pants etc.

On selecting individual UVs, Blender shows the selected UV along with the other UVs in the UV editor.

Before unwrapping new UV maps, these UVs were ***"Reset"***, still other UVs show along with the selected UV in the editor.

Also, UV **Pinning** is not applied.

Changing **Texture Mapping** to UV and selecting different part UVs doesn't change anything.

How to show "Individual UVs" in a multi UV map and also is there any way to create UV "vertex groups"?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). But these are individual UV maps. You cannot unwrap a mesh *partially*. You can only move the unneeded parts away. Also, when adding a new UV map slot, it *duplicates* the last one.

Comment: So,is there any way to create Uv "vertex groups" for each individual part ?

Comment: Hey :). Sure, just use UV sync selection. Then the UV editor only shows selected vertices. [Why doesn't selecting a UV island select the corresponding vertices in the model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27301/78972)